# Array is lost after passed to a function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a length of 0 for the incoming array to this method below and undefined for the array properties that's being passed in below and not sure why:

```
function BindAlbumDropdownList(aAlbums, defaultAlbumID)
{
    if(aAlbums.length == 0)
        return;

    var albumDropdownID = $("#abumDropdown").attr("id");

    AddDropdownItem("-Select an Album-", "-1", "albumDropdown");

    for(var a in aAlbums)
    {
        alert("a.name, a.id, albumDropdown: " + a.name + "|" + a.id + "|" +  albumDropdownID);
        AddDropdownItem(a.name, a.id, albumDropdownID);
    }
}
```

I'm passing in an array that was defined earlier in another method that calls this method and the array was defined and passed like this:

```
var aAlbums = GetAllAlbums(userID, accessToken);
var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;

BindAlbumDropdownList(aAlbums, defaultAlbumID)
```

GetAllAlbums is returning a variable setup like this inside it:

```
var aFacebookAlbums = []; // array
```

and returns this array once populated.

but when I enter the for loop in the BindAlbumDropdownList, I'm getting undefined for the array properties as well as the check for length is zero

here's what the alert is giving me:

```
a.name, a.id, albumDropdown: undefined|undefined|albumDropdown
```

I am positive GetAllAlbums is returning an array with values in it because
`var defaultAlbumID = aAlbum[0].id;` gives me a valid value

I noticed that it seems like BindAlbumDropdownList doesn't really know the incoming aAlbums is an array even though I am passing an array to it.  Because I'm getting no intellisense showing the property array when trying to do aAlbum.length but I do get the .length property on the array just before I return it from the GetAllAlbums function.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#for_Statement) and not [for-in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for(i=0; i < aAlbums.length; i++)
{
    var a = aAlbums[i];
    alert("a.name, a.id, albumDropdown: " + a.name + "|" + a.id + "|" +  albumDropdownID);
    AddDropdownItem(a.name, a.id, albumDropdownID);
}
```

Comment: so basically that for(var a in ..) is the equivalent of a foreach, got it.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: You use a for ... in loop on objects, a/k/a "associative" arrays. Once you instantiate an array as an indexed array, you have to use a repeat loop like Reigel showed you.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: I added some link above... `for statement` is for arrays... `for-in statement` for objects like JSON variables...

Comment: but why would I be getting 0 for the alert out to check the length?

Comment: if(aAlbums.length == 0)
        return;

Comment: so that's why I notice that intellisense gives me no length property when I try aAlbums.length inside the BindAlbumDropdownList method but if I check the final array returned by GetAllAblums, I can alert out the array returned and see its lenth property in GetAlbums so it's like it doesn't know that the incoming value is an array in BindAlbumDropdownList

Comment: can you give a simple sample of `aAlbums` data?

Comment: var a in albums

lets say a is 3 things long

youre saying 

0.name
1.name
2.name

try a[b].name

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you included jQuery ok? Is "abumDropdown" correct for the selector id?  You can use for...in with an array in javascript even though it's not recommended.

Comment: Can you try a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

crap Ive never gotten one before and in my excitement I answered in a comment lol!!

what would you get if you asked for the value of

0.name
1.name
2.name

?

now what would you get if you asked for the value of

a[0].name
a[1].name
a[2].name

```
 for(var a in aAlbums)
    {
        alert("aAlbums[a].name, aAlbums[a].id, albumDropdown: " + a.name + "|" + a.id + "|" +  albumDropdownID);
        AddDropdownItem(aAlbums[a].name, aAlbums[a].id, albumDropdownID);
    }
```